# Cannot impose texture to object

Tags: c++, opengl

I tried to put grass texture to a simple rectangle, put I cannot force it to work.Function to bind texture to id are working properly ( tested), so it must be somewhere here, but I cannot recognise the error. Rectangle is still a white, without any textures, or any sign of trying to texture

```
void Draw()
    {
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grass);
        glPushMatrix();

        float m_amb[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
        float m_dif[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
        float m_spe[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, m_amb);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, m_dif);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, m_spe);

        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(place.x - 15.0f, place.y - 15.0f, place.z - 5.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(place.x +15.0f, place.y - 15.0f, place.z - 5.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(place.x + 15.0f, place.y + 15.0f, place.z - 5.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(place.x - 15.0f, place.y + 15.0f, place.z - 5.0f);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
    }
```

Comment: you really need to check the result of the OpenGL functions, one is probably failing which is the cause of your problem

Comment: `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` is not allowed in between [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequences. This will gain a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error. Move it after the `glEnd` instruction. But since this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is impossible to say if this is the major issue.

Comment: The [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequence should only enclose the `glTexCoord2f`, `glNormal3f` and `glVertex3f` instructions.

Comment: so i moved glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); behind glEnd but it doesnt work ,so it's not this one

Comment: @Saper9 Read the other comments too! Move `glBegin(GL_QUADS);` just before `glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);`!

Comment: @Rabbid76 sorry for my stupidness. I did that and now everything is working, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In between [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequences are no other commands allowed, than that which are used to specify vertex attributes, like as `glTexCoord2f`, `glNormal3f` and `glVertex3f`.

A disregard of that, will produce a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error, as mentioned at the OpenGL reference page of [`glBegin`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml).

To solve the issue, you have to move `glBegin(GL_QUADS);` right before the first `glTexCoord2f` instruction and `glEnd();` directly after the last `glVertex3f` instruction:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(place.x - 15.0f, place.y - 15.0f, place.z - 5.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(place.x +15.0f, place.y - 15.0f, place.z - 5.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(place.x + 15.0f, place.y + 15.0f, place.z - 5.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(place.x - 15.0f, place.y + 15.0f, place.z - 5.0f);
glEnd();
```